# PXE: File loading time

Tags: pxe

While PXE booting a system, it looks for UUID file at PXE server. If found then it proceed accordingly.
Else System waits for 2 min and then starts looking for MacID file on PXE Server.

Is there any way to set this file searching time ?

**Update1:**
Underlying pxe bootloader is PXELINUX

Comment: As far as I know, the PXE boot firmware will first make a DHCP request, and then will download whichever file is indicated by the DHCP response, and then execute it. This would be the PXE "network bootstrap program", or more simply the PXE bootloader. Anything that happens at this point depends on which PXE bootloader program you're using... and you have not told us that. Please, we don't want to play guess-the-bootloader. Are you using iPXE, PXELINUX, a PXE version of GRUB, or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to upvote your question because I am struggling with issues in this area, but you have not added relevant info to help us understand the situation. :( If you add detail as @telcoM has suggested I am happy to upvote this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late answer, but maybe it will help others...

In my experience, PXELINUX will not wait for 2 minutes: it will iterate between the potential configuration file name forms (client UUID, client MAC address, whole IP address in hex, partial IP address in hex, and finally `default`) as quickly as the TFTP server will tell it that a previous file was not found.

Is your TFTP server perhaps configured to attempt DNS lookups and/or `identd` queries (because of tcpwrapper/`libwrap` configuration?) on any incoming connection? If your DNS servers are not responding to the TFTP server host, and/or the TFTP server's `identd` queries are using the default timeout values, it might be possible to get worst-case delays of about 2 minutes.

A PXE client is not going to be responding to `identd` queries, so attempting them in conjunction with incoming TFTP connections is probably just a waste of time. So for example, if your PXE boot clients are in IP block 192.168.*.*, then you should make sure your `/etc/hosts.allow` has a dedicated line like this:

```
in.tftpd:  127.0.0.1 [::1] 192.168.0.0/16
```

instead of relying on a default line which might include an `ALL@` prefix (which will trigger an useless `identd` query) and/or might be name-based (which will trigger DNS lookups before the the TFTP server can be allowed to process the incoming request). The `in.tftpd` part may vary depending on which TFTP server you're using and/or whether it is stand-alone or `[x]inetd`-based.

Troubleshooting a PXE bootloader may require dumping the network traffic on the DHCP and/or TFTP ports to see how far it is getting and if it's receiving valid answers from the TFTP server, but try first increasing the logging level of the TFTP server so that it logs all the requests it gets and responses it sends out, and seeing if that helps you figure out the problem.

A common problem is that the pathname of the file requested with TFTP is not exactly what you expect, or that your TFTP server maps it into its filesystem in an unexpected way. For example, if using a Windows server to supply the PXELINUX configuration files, you might need to configure the Windows TFTP server to also accept Unix-style forward slashes as path separators, instead of only Windows-style backslashes.

The only DHCP-adjustable timeout value in PXELINUX is the reboot time value (DHCP option 211), and its default value is 300 seconds, not two minutes. Because PXELINUX's DHCP options used to be in the range reserved for site-specific options (before [RFC 3942](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3942)), you may need to also supply a specific "magic" value in DHCP option 208 as a way of confirmation that the DHCP option range 208-211 is actually intended for PXELINUX and not to some other site-specific use. See [RFC 5071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5071) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Since I was not able to track down the issue, I make the another move and modified the source code of pxelinux.0 to look for MacID directly rather UUID.